# Is there a way to change the lookup_value of the Macro code with the identified cell address?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change the lookup_value of **`RC[-2]`** with the address **`Cells(3,2)`** on the macro code below.

```
Range("D4").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[Reference Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C3:R12C3,1,0)"
Range("D4:D10").FillDown
```

I am trying to apply the formula of vlookup on multiple sheets but it is not always on *`RC[-2]`* as it varies from sheet to sheet. I have already identified what lookup_value cell on each sheet, but it is on this format **`Cells(3,2)`** I have used `.Find` to identify what cell to use. I'm also going to apply the `selection.filldown` for the rest of the entries on each sheet.

Comment: Try `"=VLOOKUP(" & variable & ",[Reference Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C3:R12C3,1,0)"` where you set variable to `cells(3,2)`?

Comment: @findwindow the variable will show the value of the cell. This is what i did in setting the variable`Set DataLookupValue = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Find(What:="Data")`